# CefSharp crashed on Windows 7 & 8.1 but runs on Windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, cefsharp, squirrel.windows

We are having problems distrusting our app containing CefSharp, the issue relates to the VC++ 2015 redistributable files.

To investigate we are testing with the CefSharp MinimalExample for WPF. In addition to the files required for the app we have included concrt140.dll, msvcp140.dll, vcruntime140.dll and vccorlib140.dll. The demo app works ok on a clean install of Windows 10 but crashes on Windows 7 & 8.1 at the point of creating an instance of CefSettings.

If we install the VC++ 2015 redistributable manually the demo app starts working. If we then uninstall the c++ redistributable via control panel the app ‘continues to work’. If we then delete the four files mentioned above the app crashes (as I would expect).

We use Squirrel for Windows to distribute our app which does not support merge modules, therefore the only option we have is to include the VC++ files with the app.

Any ideas how we can get this to work on Windows 7 & 8.1 without asking customers to manually install the VC++ redistributables?

Comment: CefSharp has a bunch of unmanaged DLLs that need to be deployed.  These C++ runtime DLLs are just part of it, even though it doesn't get mentioned often enough.  Running the redist installer is one way to do it, but it is just as easy to include them in the same directory as the other DLLs.  Well, easier if you don't want to create an installer.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 & Windows 8.1 (not Windows 10) we had to include 20 c++ redistibutable files all prefixed with 'api-ms-win-'. With these included everything works fine.